# Hiding class via javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, joomla

This piece of javascript code is not running for some reason even though I think it's 100% correct.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if($("#porder30").html() == "")
{
$(".containertest30").css('display', 'none');
}
else {
$(".containertest30").css('display', '');
}
});
```

"#porder30" is the ID of a "table **td**" with a value. Sometimes this  will have a value in it, other times it won't. Currently, it's hiding the class even if "#porder30" does in fact have a value.

Comment: Fundamentally, that should work. Probably `html()` is returning a string that isn't blank (perhaps it has spaces or newlines in it). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Note: You probably want to look at [`show`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/), and [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) (particularly `toggle` as it accepts a flag, which would make the code much more concise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`if ($("#porder30").text().trim() == '') { ... }`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I don't think I've struggled with such a small piece of code for so long. Super grateful

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get it going with:

```
if (document.getElementById("porder30").textContent == "") {
  document.getElementById("containertest30").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply :) Both of the answers are working!